# VB.net JSON If Using Textbox text in statment

Tags: json, vb.net

Hi there im currently having an issue where the following code will work

```
If(jResults("items")("head") Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")("head")("icon").ToString())
```

however if i try to substitute a value with a textbox i cant get it to work

```
If(jResults("items")( + itemtypelbl.Text + ) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items") ("itemtypelbl.Text")("icon").ToString())
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have always seen IF/THEN differently

Comment: Try using: `If(jResults("items")+ itemtypelbl.Text  Is Nothing, "", jResults("items") ("itemtypelbl.Text")("icon").ToString())`

Comment: unfortunatly that did not work i get the error `operator '+' is not defined for types 'newtonsoft.json.linq.jtoken' And 'String'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is exactly as you have in your question, the problem is the lack of anything before the first `+` and after the second `+`. You need to have an *operand* either side of an operation like `+`.

*EDIT:* I also just saw that the name of the textbox should not be in quotes, as you are trying to access a variable property, not a hard-coded string.

Here is what I think your code should be:

```
If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items") (itemtypelbl.Text)("icon").ToString())
```

Comment: please could you elborate a little more with using my code as an example as i have tried and seem to be failing `If(jResults("items")( + itemtypelbl.Text + ) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items") ("itemtypelbl.Text")("icon").ToString())`